# For $Y\subseteq X$ If $\rm{Int_{Y}(A)}=\rm{Int_X(A)}\cap Y$ for all $A\subseteq Y$ then $Y$ in open set on $X$.

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\tau)$ a topological space and $Y\subseteq X$. Show that if $\rm{Int_{Y}(A)}=\rm{Int_X(A)}\cap Y$ for all $A\subseteq Y$ then $Y$ in open set on $X$.

I showed for $A=Y$ that $\rm{Int_{Y}(Y)}=\rm{Int_X(Y)}$ but I can't show that $Y$ is open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $Y=A$, $Y=int_Y(Y)=int_X(Y)\cap Y$ implies that $Y=int_X(Y)$ and $Y$ is open.

Comment: Why take $Y=int_Y(Y)$?

Comment: @LuisPrado Every set is open in itself, that's in the definition of a topology.

Comment: because an open subset of $Y$ for the induced topology is of the form $U\cap Y$ where $U$ is open in $X$, take $U=X$ you deduce that $X\cap Y=Y$ so $Y$ is open for the induced topology so $int_Y(Y)=Y$.