# About a relationship between topological subspaces

Tags: general-topology

Let A be a subspace of $X$ and let $D\subset A$. Let $\text{Int}_AD$ and $\text{Int}_XD$ denote the interior of $D$ in the subspace topology on $A$ and the interior of $D$ in the  topology on $X$ respectively. I am required to show that $\text{Int}_AD\subset A\cap\text{Int}_XD $ but I feel like I have found a counterexample:

Let $A=[0,2]$ be a subspace of $\mathbb R$ with the standard topology. Let $D=[0,1]$.

Since $(-1,1)$ is open in $\mathbb R$, it follows that $(-1,1)\cap [0,2]=[0,1)$ is an open set in the subspace topology on $A$. Hence, $D\cap [0,1)=[0,1)$ makes up $\text{Int}_AD$, hence $0\in\text{Int}_AD$.

However, $\text{Int}_XD=(0,1)$ which obviously does not contain $0$, hence $0\notin A\cap \text{Int}_XD$.

Is there something wrong with my counterexample? Or how should we modify our conditions so that $\text{Int}_AD\subset A\cap\text{Int}_XD $ will hold?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For $Y\subseteq X$ If $\rm{Int_{Y}(A)}=\rm{Int_X(A)}\cap Y$ for all $A\subseteq Y$ then $Y$ in open set on $X$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2498556/for-y-subseteq-x-if-rmint-ya-rmint-xa-cap-y-for-all-a-subseteq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your counterexample is good. In fact, $\operatorname{int}_XD\subseteq\operatorname{int}_AD$ is correct (the reverse inclusion). Perhaps this is what the exercise was supposed to be...

Therefore, $\operatorname{int}_AD\subseteq\operatorname{int}_XD$ iff. $\operatorname{int}_XD=\operatorname{int}_AD$. (you can drop the $A\cap\cdots$ because $D\subseteq A$).

This will be true, for example, if $A$ is open in $X$, but this is not a necessary condition. Consider, for instance, the indiscrete topology on a set with more than one element.